# RegEx matching a specific TLD

Tags: regex

I'm working on a RegEx that should match a specific TLD, but I'm probably going through too many steps (which I would like to keep as less as possible in order to do not overload the engine):
The idea is to match URLs using the TLD ".net" (and not the whole domain):

1. hxxp://us.netprinting.com/
2. hxxps://us.netprinting.com/
3. hxxps://us.net
4. mycar.netto.com/login
5. www.wonderfulday.net:80/login
6. myhouse.net:443

I'm working on this one and so far I'm matching only the #3 and #5 but not the #6:

```
/(?<=\/\/|\.(?!-))[a-z0-9-]+(?<!-)\.net\b(?!\.)/g
```

Am I going too wild or you see a more lighter way to accomplish this?

Thank you so much.

Comment: You should tell us which should(n't) match

Comment: URLs or FQDNs having ".net" as top level domain.

Comment: which flavor is it ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
\.net(?:[:\/]|$)
```

it will match `.net` followed by a `:` or a `/` or the end of line. See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/lD6jN9/2)

Comment: Besides the fact you don't need to filter the string before you can use it?